# Generating pseudo-random 16-bit integers

Tags: c++, c++11, random, mersenne-twister

I need to generate 16-bit pseudo-random integers and I am wondering what the best choice is.

The obvious way that comes in my mind is something as follows:

```
std::random_device rd;
auto seed_data = std::array<int, std::mt19937::state_size> {};
std::generate(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data), std::ref(rd));
std::seed_seq seq(std::begin(seed_data), std::end(seed_data));
std::mt19937 generator(seq);
std::uniform_int_distribution<short> dis(std::numeric_limits<short>::min(), 
                                         std::numeric_limits<short>::max());

short n = dis(generator);
```

The problem I see here is that `std::mt19937` produces 32-bit unsigned integers since it's defined as this:

```
using mt19937 = mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned int, 
                                        32, 624, 397, 
                                        31, 0x9908b0df,
                                        11, 0xffffffff, 
                                        7, 0x9d2c5680, 
                                        15, 0xefc60000, 
                                        18, 1812433253>;
```

That means static casting is done and only the least significant part of these 32-bit integers is used by the distribution. So I am wondering how good are these series of pseudo-random shorts and I don't have the mathematical expertise to answer that.

I expect that a better solution would be to use your own defined `mersenne_twister_engine` engine for 16-bit integers. However, I haven't found any mentioned set for the template arguments (requirements can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/mersenne-twister-engine-class?view=vs-2017) for instance). Are there any?

**UPDATE**: I updated the code sample with proper initialization for the distribution.

Comment: Why not set the [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) distrubution range properly: `std::uniform_int_distribution<short> dis(std::numeric_limits<short>::min(), std::numeric_limits<short>::max());`

Comment: I expected that using the default constructor would have the same effect.

Comment: No, since the default [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/uniform_int_distribution) uses `0` as the bottom of the range.

Comment: Right, you are correct. Just checked the implementation and saw that. Should have read the documentation more carefully. Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Both comments of yours may become one good answer.

Comment: @Bob__ Ah my mistake, confusing it with floating point types.

Comment: As far as I recall the theory is the generator is simply a source of random **bits** and the *distribution* can hold *state*. So the *distribution* is free to hold a cache of bits it read from the generator and parcel them out in whatever size chunks are demanded. So, in your case the `16`bit distribution may call the generator half as often as a *distribution* configured to provide `32`bit numbers.

Comment: C's `rand` has a slightly worse distribution than C++'s twisters, but it is faster and actually only generates 16 bits of data. Intel's fast rand is faster than that and is intentionally made to mimic C's rand func (it is also 16 bit).

Comment: @vandench If by "slightly worse" you mean "terrible", then we both agree on this point. On my instance of `dieharder`, `rand()` just failed 7 out of the first 10 statistical tests, while mt19937 got 9 PASSED and one WEAK. For once, the author of a question already knows how to use `<random>` properly and you tempt him to join the dark side anyway… it boggles the mind. As far as premature optimization goes, `return 0;` is a very very fast PRNG, by the way. (Oh, and `rand()` only gives 15 signiifcant bits.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your way is indeed the correct way.

The mathematical arguments are complex (I'll try to dig out a paper), but taking the least significant bits of the Mersenne Twister, as implemented by the C++ standard library, is the correct thing to do.

If you're in any doubt as to the quality of the sequence, then run it through the diehard tests.

Comment: is it really that complex? If you take the last digit from random two digits numbers, then they are random as well. I know this is a crude simplification, but considering bits instead of digits cannot be that different. Looking forward to see the paper ;)

Comment: @user463035818: That's true for a true generator, but certainly not for others. E.g. for a linear congruential generator, the succession is typically odd->even->odd->even which means that the least significant bit is rather deterministic!

Comment: To add to the _odd->even->odd->even_: AFAIK, `rand()` is especially prone to modulo with powers of 2. The less the power of 2 the more deterministic it becomes. I once realized this practically when I intended to make a sand texture out of 4 shades of brown and `rand()`. It gave a repeating pattern (looking like a strange 70's wallpaper). Increasing the colors to 5 (a prime) yieled in turn a fully satisfying result. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There may be a misconception, considering this quote from OP's question (emphasis mine):

> The problem I see here is that std::mt19937 produces 32-bit unsigned integers […].
>   That means **static casting is done and only the least significant part of these 32-bit integers is used by the distribution**.

That's not how it works.

The following are quotes from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

> The random number library provides classes that generate random and
>   pseudo-random numbers. These classes include:
>
> - Uniform random bit generators (URBGs), […];
> - Random number distributions (e.g. uniform, normal, or poisson distributions) which convert the output of URBGs into various statistical distributions
>
> URBGs and distributions are designed to be used together to produce random values.

So a uniform random bit generator, like `mt19937` or `random_device`

> is a function object returning unsigned integer values such that each value in the range of possible results has (ideally) equal probability of being returned.

While a random number distribution, like `uniform_int_distribution`

> **post-processes the output of a URBG in such a way** that resulting output is distributed according to a defined statistical probability density function.

The way it's done uses **all** the bits from the source to produce an output. As an example, we can look at the implementation of `std::uniform_distribution` in  [`libstdc++`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/libstdc%2B%2B-api-4.5/a00987_source.html) (starting at line 824), which can be roughly simplified as

```
template <typename Type>
class uniform_distribution
{
    Type a_ = 0, b_ = std::numeric_limits<Type>::max();
public:
    uniform_distribution(Type a, Type b) : a_{a}, b_{b} {}
    template<typename URBG>
    Type operator() (URBG &gen)
    {
        using urbg_type = std::make_unsigned_t<typename URBG::result_type>;
        using u_type    = std::make_unsigned_t<Type>;
        using max_type  = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(urbg_type) > sizeof(u_type))
                                            , urbg_type, u_type>;

        urbg_type urbg_min = gen.min();
        urbg_type urbg_max = gen.max();
        urbg_type urbg_range = urbg_max - urbg_min;

        max_type urange = b_ - a_;
        max_type udenom = urbg_range <= urange ? 1 : urbg_range / (urange + 1);

        Type ret;
        // Note that the calculation may require more than one call to the generator
        do
            ret = (urbg_type(gen()) - urbg_min ) / udenom;
            // which is 'ret = gen / 65535' with OP's parameters
            // not a simple cast or bit shift
        while (ret > b_ - a_);
        return ret + a_;
    }
};
```

This could be tested [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/prJDP22ocbKgpNLE).